# Music playlist ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having trouble trying to only allow a user to play one song at a time. Currently if a user is listening to their playlist they are able to push play on multiple songs. I have screenshot and pasted the code below!

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @playlist.title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>User:</strong>
  <%= @playlist.user_id %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_playlist_path(@playlist) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', playlists_path %>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Track Name</th>
            <th>Track MP3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <%if @playlist.tracks.present? %>
            <% @playlist.tracks.each do|track|%>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3">
                      <%=  track.name%>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%if track.mp3.attached?%>
                            <audio controls>
                              <source src="<%= rails_blob_path(track.mp3) %>" type="audio/mpeg">
                            </audio>
                        <%end%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <%end%>
        <%end%>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYZ6D.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [onplay](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onplay.asp) event to trigger a function that stops all players except the player that triggered the event.